# How to auto redirect IP address to a login PHP script?

Tags: php, html, wamp, wampserver

I am using WAMP server, and I am a novice. 
Currently, I have many scripts under `/www/mySite`. 
I have set `/www/mySite` as my default location for the wamp server.

However, when you set the browser address to `http://myIPAddress`, it automatically shows a list of files under `/www/mySite`.

I don't want this. When the user points to `http://myIPAddress`, I want it to point directly to `http://myIPAddress/main_login.php`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: i think usually it works if you tried `index.php` as your `main_login.php` ! let me know !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The simplest way is to rename your main_login.php to index.php
2. You can also do it using your server configuration or .htaccess
3. You may include another index.php and use its header like this

   ```
   <?php
   $redirection_url='main_login.php';
   header('Location: '. $redirection_url);
   ?>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of main_login.php to index.php (index.* is something apache reads as default page) or learn about .htaccess and redirect "/" (which is root of your webserver) to main_login.php

Comment: Please explain about how to work .htaccess and redirection.

Comment: just type here in stack or in google "how to use .htaccess" and follow tutorials, it is kind of too hard to explain it in few words.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are two ways:

- Changing the Apache configuration file an telling Apache to look up all the *main_login.php* file (by default it gets all the index files)
- Changing the name of your file from *main_login.php* to *index.php*

### **Changing Apache configuration file**

To change the Apache configuration file you must

- Go to the httpd.conf file
- Look for the *DirectoryIndex* row line
- Edit it as you wish
- Restart Apache

### **Renaaming your file**

It's the simplest and best way.